# Vim search replace regex + incremental function

Tags: regex, function, vim, increment, inkscape

I'm currently stuck in vim trying to find a search/replace oneliner to replace a number with another + increment for each new iteration = when it finds a new match.

I'm working in xml svg code to batch process files Inkscape cannot process the text (plain svg multiline text bug).

```
<tspan
       x="938.91315"
       y="783.20563"
       id="tspan13017"
       style="font-weight:bold">Text1:</tspan><tspan
       x="938.91315"
       y="833.20563"
       id="tspan13019">Text2</tspan><tspan
       x="938.91315"
       y="883.20563"
       id="tspan13021">✗Text3</tspan>
```

etc.

So what I want to do is to change that to this result:

```
<tspan
       x="938.91315"
       y="200"
       id="tspan13017"
       style="font-weight:bold">Text1:</tspan><tspan
       x="938.91315"
       y="240"
       id="tspan13019">Text2</tspan><tspan
       x="938.91315"
       y="280"
       id="tspan13021">✗Text3</tspan>
```

etc.

So I duckducked and found the best vim tips resource from zzapper, but I cannot understand it:

> convert yy to 10,11,12 :
>
> :let i=10 | ’a,’bg/Abc/s/yy/\=i/ |let i=i+1

I then adapted it to something I can understand and should work in my home vim:

```
:let i=300 | 327,$ smagic ! y=\"[0-9]\+.[0-9]\+\" ! \=i ! g | let i=i+50
```

But somehow it doesn't loop, all I get is that:

```
<tspan
       x="938.91315"
       300
       id="tspan13017"
       style="font-weight:bold">Text1:</tspan><tspan
       x="938.91315"
       300
       id="tspan13019">Text2</tspan><tspan
       x="938.91315"
       300
       id="tspan13021">✗Text3</tspan>
```

So here I'm seriously stuck. I cannot figure out what doesn't work :

- My adaptation of the original formula ?
- My data layout ?
- My .vimrc ?

I'll try to find other resources by myself, but on that kind of trick they are pretty rare I find, and like in zzapper tips, not always delivered with a manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to fix it:

```
:let i = 300 | g/\m\<y=/ s/\my="\zs\d\+.\d\+\ze"/\=i/ | let i += 50
```

Translation:

- `let i = 300` - hopefully obvious
- `g/\m\<y=/ ...` - for all lines matching `\m\<y=`, apply the following command; the "following command" is `s/.../.../ | let ...`; the regexp:

  - `\m` - "magic" regexp
  - `\<` - match only at word boundary
- `s/\my="\zs\d\+.\d\+\ze"/\=i/` - substitute; the regexp:

  - `\m` - "magic" regexp
  - `\d\+` - one or more digits
  - `\zs...\ze` - replace only what is matched between these points
  - `\=i` - replace with the value of expression `i`
- `let i += 50` - hopefully obvious again.

For more information: `:help :g`, `:help \zs`, `:help \ze`, `help s/\\=`.

Comment: Thank you ! Works perfectly ! And, your explanations helped me to extend my clumsy formula once I understood that it is the :g command that enables the loop behaviour. My take then is :let i=300 | 323,$g/y="/smagic![0-9]\+.[0-9]\+!\=i!g | let i+=50 I'll put it as well as answer, for those like me who are lost when there is too much letters and backslashing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my take as a memo (wrote this as an answer as an EDIT didn't seem right). Sorry it is not the best vim scripting here but it enables me to understand (I'm not a vim specialist).

```
:let i=300 | 323,$g/y="/smagic![0-9]\+.[0-9]\+!\=i!g | let i+=50
```

Assign the initial value to i :

```
:let i=300
```

Start :global (:g) function from line 323 to the end of file:

```
323,$g
```

Pattern to match for executing the commands (litteral text here)

```
y="
```

Substitution with magic on (magic meaning special characters "enabled")

```
smagic
```

Pattern to find

```
[0-9]\+.[0-9]\+
```

(numbers between 0-9 one or more times, a litteral dot, the numbers again)

Replaced with

```
\=i
```

\= tells vim to evaluate i not to write it litterally

Increment i with 50 for the next iteration

```
let i+=50
```

This part is still in the g function.

The separators, in bold:
**|** are the separators between the different functions
**/** are the separators in the :g function
**!** are the separators in the smagic function