# Inkscape doesn't allow to edit svg text lines once it has been saved as plain svg or treated with scour

Tags: svg, sed, inkscape

I was for several days trying to find a solution to the following problem :

- Create a svg with text (simply click with the text tool to add text, do not drag to open a frame)
- Type enter to create a multiline text, add several lines of text
- Save as plain svg or optimized svg
- Or treat with scour in command-line

Reopen with Inkscape : you cannot edit the text, it shows it properly but when you go to the next line (with the mouse or keyboard arrow down) the cursor stays on the first line.

This is an annoying bug running for some time in Inkscape and doesn't help with web edition.

But there are solutions... See the following thread to manually (in vim) replace all tspans : 
[Vim search replace regex + incremental function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317532/vim-search-replace-regex-incremental-function)

And see my answer below to correct the svg code in order to get your Inkscape files back in working order !!!

Answer (score 1):

Sed is very useful in order to correct your files in a batch:

```
cd /home/user/my/svg/files
sed -i.bak 's|<svg|<svg\nxmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"\nxmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"|g' *.svg
```

This runs on all svg files in the current folder and :

1. Creates a `.bak` file which you can rename to svg in order to get your original files (but I nevertheless strongly advocate to duplicate your working folder in order to avoid terrible mistakes when fiddling with sed)
2. Adds the correct namespaces with newlines (`\n`)

Then:

```
sed -i.2.bak 's|<tspan|<tspan sodipodi:role="line" |g' *.svg
```

This appends `sodipodi:role="line"` to all tspan tags in the current folder and creates `file.2.bak` backups.

Comment: As a sidenote, there is an option in scour to keep editor data, but I'm not sure it still optimizes the svg then.

Answer (score 0):

SVG files do not currently support multi-line text.  Inkscape uses custom XML attributes to keep track of which spans of text are part of that block of text.

When you save as Optimized SVG, Inkscape strips out all its custom XML attributes and writes a vanilla SVG file.  So the sense of what is a block of text is gone.

Comment: Yes but hopefully scour doesn't remove the `<text>` including the `<tspans>`. When you create a proper (flowing) block of text by first creating a frame with text tool, it doesn't display properly in a browser or even in nautilus file explorer... I really cannot understand why this limitation. SVG could be such a fantastic publishing format with support for multiline text flow.

Comment: SVG files are intended as a graphic description format.  Not unlike PDFs.  It doesn't really have any automatic layout features.  Having said that, simple multi-line text is probably going to be a part of SVG2.